# How does the number of iterations affect convergence in a self-organizing map?

Tags: r, som, self-organizing-maps

I'm training a self-organizing map (SOM) using the `kohonen` library in R and I get some confusing results when I adjust the `rlen` parameter in the `som` call. According to the help file, `rlen` is the "the number of times the complete data set will be presented to the network," which seems straightforward enough. The confusing result happens when I view the convergence of the algorithm via `plot(som_model, type="changes")` for different values of `rlen`. This plot shows iterations vs. the average distance to a data vector, and from what I understand when we see it plateau we can assume the algorithm has converged.  But as shown below, the number of iterations required for convergence seems to be a function of the number of iterations selected.

Using the built-in `wines` data set, I first plot the results with 300 iterations via:

```
som_model = som(scale(wines), grid = somgrid(6, 4, "hexagonal"), rlen = 300)
par(mar = c(5, 5, 1, 1))
plot(som_model, type="changes", main = "rlen=300")
```

As can be seen, the mean distance plateaus after ~200 iterations

[image]

If I then then repeat this with `rlen=1000`, I get the following:

[image]

Now the mean distance plateaus at around 600 iterations. I suppose there is some consistency in that the plateau appears about 2/3 of the way through the number of iterations. But if I'm just changing how many times the data is presented to the SOM network, then why would things not converge at 200 iterations in both cases. I'm guessing I have a misunderstanding about what the algorithm is actually doing. Any help anyone can offer is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [vignette](https://clarkdatalabs.github.io/soms/SOM_NBA):

> Several parameters of convergence force the adjustments to get smaller
> and smaller as training vectors are fed in many times, causing the map
> to stabilize into a representation.

The parameters are going to be adjusted for `rlen`--a larger `rlen` allows for smaller steps and presumably a more stable convergence. So, if a model is having a hard time converging, a larger value for `rlen` may be needed. And, obviously, if `rlen` is too small, it may not exhibit convergence (e.g., `rlen = 60` on the `wines` dataset).

Another way to think about it--the weight of each training vector fed to the model is something like inversely proportional to `rlen`, so it takes more training vectors to achieve the same "movement" away from the initial vector with larger `rlen` values.

Comment: Got it. Could I interpret this as the neighborhood function that updates the nodes around the best matching unit making smaller adjustments when the `rlen` is larger.

Comment: That matches my understanding.